# HTTP/2 test not possible. Host not found or connection refused

Tags: nginx, http, http2

В общем столкнулся со странной проблемой, решил я посмотреть, использует ли мой сайт http2 https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test (нет не использует, но я просто хотел увидеть в ответе http 1.1). Вместо этого получил ошибку - HTTP/2 test not possible. Host not found or connection refused. Хотя сайт работает... Я ума не приложу, в чем ошибка, чужие сайты там тестятся отлично, а мои - нет. Очевидно, чего то не хватает у меня. Подскажите, что это может быть?

Comment: Не вижу проблем, тулза тестирует возможность http2, причем здесь http1.1?

Comment: проблема в том, что он тестирует http2, а если его нет, пишет http 1.1, но никак не выдает ошибку

Comment: Попробовал ради интереса mail.ru и ya.ru - результаты разные. Яндекс не поддерживает http2 и ничего не сказано про http1.1. Так что тулза, скажем так, с особенностями.

Comment: Negative! ya.ru does not support HTTP/2.0. на ya.ru , он видит что нет http2, у меня же не видит моего существования впринципе))

Comment: Если ваши сайты действительно "торчат" в интернете (резолвятся, доступны и т.д.), то попробуйте любой другой http2 тестер, может этот не может по каким-то причинам достучаться.

Comment: На всякий случай спросу, а ваш сайт на https?

Comment: нет , обычный http

Comment: Ну так несмотря на спецификацию, в реальности практически никто не поддерживает http2 без tls (https)